# How to get hex-encoded md5 hash in Go

Tags: hash, md5, go

I'm trying to get the md5 hash of a file in Go, like thus:

```
running_hash := md5.New(); // type hash.Hash
running_hash.Write(data);  // data is []byte
sum := running_hash.Sum(); // []uint8 according to the compiler
```

But when I try to get the string of the hash's 'sum' (http://golang.org/pkg/hash/), via

```
sumstring := string(sum);  // returns 'Ӿ��]앿��N��' or similar
```

when the hash is supposed to be `d3be9e835dec95bfbef34ebe1fbf03da`. I get the same sort of nonsense, only with different characters, when I try to convert on a byte-by-byte basis.

How am I meant to get the hash's string?

Comment: You want a `base-16` representation of the hash,

Comment: Bear in mind: The output of a hash function is a binary value. The hex representation you're used to seeing is just a convention.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basically, you've got the binary data but it looks like you're expecting hex. Have a look at the [hex](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/) package for conversion routines, especially [`EncodeToString`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#EncodeToString). I'm not a Go programmer, but I think if you just pass `sum` into `hex.EncodeToString`, you'll get the answer you expected.

Answer (score 9):

alternately, you can get the hex representation of a string or byte slice easily using `fmt.Sprintf("%x", sum)`

Comment: IMO this should be the preferred solution.