# Slice can not convert to string

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, slice

```
func (this *AdminModel) Login(v_name string, v_pwd string) (bool, error, uint) {
    o := orm.NewOrm()
    v_pwd_encrypt_byte := md5.Sum([]byte(v_pwd))
    v_pwd_encrypt := string(v_pwd_encrypt_byte[:])
    t_admin := Admin{Name: v_name, Pwd: v_pwd_encrypt}
    fmt.Printf("username:%v  password:%v\n", v_name, v_pwd_encrypt_byte)
    fmt.Printf("username:%v  password:%v\n", v_name, v_pwd_encrypt_byte[:])
    fmt.Printf("username:%v  password:%v\n", v_name, v_pwd_encrypt)
    err := o.Read(&t_admin, "Name", "Pwd")
    if err != nil {
        return false, err, 0
    } else {
        return true, nil, t_admin.Id
    }
}
```

print result:

```
username:yuhaya  password:[97 22 175 237 203 11 195 16 131 147 92 28 38 47 244 201]
username:yuhaya  password:[97 22 175 237 203 11 195 16 131 147 92 28 38 47 244 201]
username:yuhaya  password:a???
                          ???\&/??
```

Why the last line of the printing results gibberish?

```
v_pwd_encrypt := string(v_pwd_encrypt_byte[:])
```

Is this position convert out of the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get hex-encoded md5 hash in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988543/how-to-get-hex-encoded-md5-hash-in-go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @Ainar-G's answer, [`hex.EncodeToString`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#EncodeToString) is the most efficient way to do it since it doesn't involve reflection or type guessing like `fmt.Sprintf`.

```
func main() {
    sum := md5.Sum([]byte("meh"))
    stringSum := hex.EncodeToString(sum[:])
    fmt.Println(stringSum)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`md5.Sum()` returns bytes, not printable ASCII characters. If you want to see hex representation of those bytes, you can use `fmt.Sprintf("%x", ...)`, like this:

```
v_pwd_encrypt := fmt.Sprintf("%x", v_pwd_encrypt_byte)
```